# Is there a way to connect an ESP32 to a Mosquitto broker by using the Mosquitto machine hostname instead of the machine IP?

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I am configuring an ESP32 to connect to a Mosquitto MQTT broker on an windows11 machine. The windows11 machine's hostname is "home" and it's local network IP is 192.168.0.5. My ESP32 MQTT code works perfectly when I use the following:

```
    esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg = {
      .uri = "mqtt://192.168.0.5:1883",
```

However, when i try using the machine name instead of the IP, I get an error message:

```
   esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg = {
      .uri = "mqtt://home:1883",
E (4147) MQTT_CLIENT: Error transport connect
```

I tried this combination below, still not connecting with host name.

```
   esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg = {
      .uri = "mqtt://home.local:1883",
```

Any idea how to fix this problem so I can use "home" instead of "192.168.0.5" ?

Below is the mqtt config for ref,

```
 esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg = {
    // .uri = "mqtt://broker.emqx.io:1883",
  //  .uri = "mqtt://192.168.0.5:1883",
      .uri = "mqtt://home:1883",
    .event_handle = mqtt_event_handler,
    .client_id = (const char *)SN,
    .lwt_topic = "/device/send-data/mqtt-will",
    .lwt_msg = (const char *)local_data,
    .lwt_msg_len = 50,
    .task_stack = 4096,
    .buffer_size = 2000,
    .lwt_qos = 0,
    // .username = "admin",
    // .password ="admin",
    .keepalive = 30,
    .lwt_retain = 0,
    // .user_context = (void *)your_context
};
```

Comment: You could use `ESPmDNS.h` or something similar to resolve the hostname manually before connect to your broker. See [it's docs](https://espressif.github.io/esp-protocols/mdns/en/index.html)

Comment: don't mistake windows hostname with a DNS, you need to actually have a DNS server on your windows machine with correct configuration on your local router to be able to access the device using a DNS address, moreover if your windows machine ip is dynamic then you might get in trouble with the DNS resolver cache